# Create a rectangular mesh from three vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three vector3 and I need to create a rectangular mesh from them.

With

```
var plane = new Plane(Vector3_1, Vector3_2, Vector3_3);
```

I get the plane but that's not what I'm looking for.
I already have the code to create a mesh but I have trouble finding the missing Vector3. I searched a lot in the forums and in the Unity docs but without finding indications about it.

Do you have any links to tell me to figure out how to find this value?

Comment: What are the Vectors you already have?  The constructor for a only Plane needs either 3 points on the plane, or a single point and a normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my method that I sketched up in a minute:

[image]

You'll need to loop through the three points to find out which point forms 90 with the other two points, as this is opposite the 4th point. This point is called P in the diagram, and A and B are the other 2 points.

From here we can simply add A and B and minus P to get our 4th point.

Here is some rough code:

```
public Vector3 Find4th(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c) {

    Vector3 point, cornerA, cornerB;

    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[] {a, b, c};
    float angleDelta = 180;
    int pointIndex = -1;

    //find point with angle closest to 90 degrees
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        point = points[i];

        cornerA = points[i != 0 ? i-1 : 2];
        cornerB = points[i != 2 ? i+1 : 0];

        Vector3 lineA = cornerA - point;
        Vector3 lineB = cornerB - point;

        float ang = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(lineA, lineB)-90);

        if (ang < angleDelta) {
            angleDelta = ang;
            pointIndex = i;
        }
    }

    point = points[pointIndex];
    cornerA = points[pointIndex != 0 ? pointIndex-1 : 2];
    cornerB = points[pointIndex != 2 ? pointIndex+1 : 0];

    return cornerA + cornerB - point;
}
```

My test script https://pastebin.com/mKhNq9ZD produces the expected results for the tests I ran.

Comment: The cross product of 2 direction vectors will give you a vector perpendicular to both. Repeat as needed.

Comment: @Draco18s Because he said that a Plane wasn't what he wanted and that he wanted to create a Mesh and needed 4 points,  I assumed he wanted a rectangle with each vector being a corner of the rectangle. Cross product isn't needed here.

Comment: However, there is a problem. If for example I use these three coordinates (-0.9, -3.1, -5.4), (-0.6, -3.1, -6.2), (-1.2, -3.1, -8.9) I get (-1.4, -3.1, -8.1) that is right. But if I start from (-1.4, -3.1, -8.1) and always turn clockwise I don't get (-1.2, -3.1, -8.9) but (-1.8, -3.1, -7.3) which does not close the rectangle but falls on the opposite side. For clarity, if I start from point "P" of the photo I don't get "B" on the right of "P" but on the left.

Comment: I see. When I did this I had intended it to work on rectangles (corners all with 90 degrees), where this isn't a problem. When you start working with corners that aren't 90 degrees, it will create a parallelogram, there are 3 possible parallelograms that it can make, and it doesn't know which of these you want.

https://i.imgur.com/WRKzRCu.png